# From biased coins to biased coins, as efficiently as possible

Tags: pr.probability, simulation

### Background

We're given a coin that shows heads with an unknown probability, $\lambda$. The goal is to use that coin (and possibly also a fair coin) to build a "new" coin that shows heads with a probability that depends on $\lambda$, call it $f(\lambda)$. This is the *Bernoulli factory problem*, and it can be solved only for certain functions $f$. (For example, flipping the coin twice and taking heads only if exactly one coin shows heads, we can simulate the probability $2\lambda(1-\lambda)$.)

Specifically, the only functions that can be simulated this way **are continuous and polynomially bounded on their domain, and map $[0, 1]$ or a subset thereof to $[0, 1]$**, as well as $f=0$ and $f=1$. These functions are called *factory functions* in this question. (A function $f(x)$ is *polynomially bounded* if both $f$ and $1-f$ are bounded below by min($x^n$, $(1-x)^n$) for some integer $n$ (Keane and O'Brien 1994). This implies that $f$ admits no roots on (0, 1) and can't take on the value 0 or 1 except possibly at 0 and/or 1.)

### Multiple-Output Bernoulli Factories

Let $J$ be a closed interval on $(0, 1)$, and let $f(\lambda):J \to (0, 1)$ be continuous.

Then by Keane and O'Brien, $f$ admits an algorithm that solves the Bernoulli factory problem given above for $f$ (using only the biased coin, in fact). A related problem is a Bernoulli factory that takes a coin with unknown probability of heads $\lambda \in J$ and produces *one or more* samples, at a time, of the probability $f(\lambda)$. This question calls it a *multiple-output Bernoulli factory*.

Obviously, any single-output Bernoulli factory can produce multiple outputs by running itself multiple times. But for some functions $f$, it may be that producing multiple outputs at a time may use fewer coin flips than producing one output multiple times.

Define the entropy bound as— $$h(f(\lambda))/h(\lambda),$$ where— $$h(x)=-x \ln(x)-(1-x) \ln(1-x),$$ is related to the Shannon entropy function.

### Questions

1. Given that a function $f(\lambda)$ is continuous and maps a closed interval in (0, 1) to (0, 1), is there a multiple-output Bernoulli factory algorithm for $f$ with an expected number of coin flips per sample that is arbitrarily close to the entropy bound, uniformly for every $\lambda$ in $f$'s domain? Call such a Bernoulli factory an *optimal factory*.  (See Nacu and Peres 2005, Question 1.)
2. Does the answer to question 1 change if the algorithm can also use a fair coin in addition to the biased coin?

### Functions with Optimal Factories

So far, the following functions do admit an optimal factory:

- The functions $\lambda$ and $1-\lambda$.
- Constants in [0, 1]. As Nacu and Peres (2005) already showed, any such constant $c$ admits an optimal factory: generate unbiased random bits using Peres's iterated von Neumann extractor (Peres 1992), then build a binary tree that generates 1 with probability $c$ and 0 otherwise (Knuth and Yao 1976).

It is easy to see that if an optimal factory exists for $f(\lambda)$, then one also exists for $1-f(\lambda)$: simply change all ones returned by the $f(\lambda)$ factory into zeros and vice versa.

Also, as Yuval Peres (Jun. 24, 2021) told me, there is an efficient multiple-output Bernoulli factory for $f(\lambda) = \lambda/2$: the key is to flip the input coin enough times to produce unbiased random bits using his extractor (Peres 1992), then multiply each unbiased bit with another input coin flip to get a sample from $\lambda/2$. Given that the sample is equal to 0, there are three possibilities that can "be extracted to produce more fair bits": either the unbiased bit is 0, or the coin flip is 0, or both are 0.  This algorithm, though, might not count as an *optimal factory*, and Peres described this algorithm only incompletely.  Indeed, the correctness might depend on how the three possibilities are "extracted to produce more fair bits"; after all, the number of coin flips per sample, for every $\lambda$, must not surpass the entropy bound.

In any case, I believe that not all factory functions admit an optimal factory described here; especially because—

- the question may depend on $f$'s range, and
- the efficiency of even a *single-output* Bernoulli factory depends on $f$'s smoothness (e.g., $O(1/n^{(r+\alpha)/2})$ only if $f$'s $r$th derivative is $\alpha$-Hölder continuous for some $\alpha \in (0, 1)$; Holtz et al. 2011).

See an [appendix in one of my articles](https://peteroupc.github.io/bernsupp.html#Multiple_Output_Bernoulli_Factory) for more information on my progress on the problem.

### References

- Keane, M. S., and O'Brien, G. L., "A Bernoulli factory", ACM Transactions on Modeling and Computer Simulation 4(2), 1994.
- Nacu, Şerban, and Yuval Peres. "Fast simulation of new coins from old", The Annals of Applied Probability 15, no. 1A (2005): 93-115.
- Knuth, Donald E. and Andrew Chi-Chih Yao. "The complexity of nonuniform random number generation", in *Algorithms and Complexity: New Directions and Recent Results*, 1976.
- Peres, Y., "[**Iterating von Neumann's procedure for extracting random bits**](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1176348543)", Annals of Statistics 1992,20,1, p. 590-597.
- Holtz, O., Nazarov, F., Peres, Y., "New Coins from Old, Smoothly", Constructive Approximation 33 (2011).